# Specifiy date type used by fullcalendar

Tags: fullcalendar

The date/time format fullcalendar uses is kind of weird.  I want to specify during the created of the calendar or somewhere in the parameters a datetime of MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM PM/AM.  Is there a way I can do this.  I read about formatdate, but didn't get any information about this

Answer (score 0):

fullCalendar has "parseDate" and offers three methods:
The string may be in ISO8601 format, IETF format, or a UNIX timestamp (in either integer or string form).
Your "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM PM/AM" seems not to match one of them.